# How to reuse the generic argument on interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have two types with same generic values:

```js
type MutationType = UseMutationResult<
  AxiosResponse<IUser>,
  unknown,
  IUser,
  unknown
>;

type MutationOptions = UseMutationOptions<
  AxiosResponse<IUser>,
  unknown,
  IUser,
  unknown
>;
```

Is it possible to reuse the similar type? Something like:

```js
// Some syntax
type T = ... <AxiosResponse<IUser>,unknown,IUser,unknown>;

type MutationType = UseMutationResult<T>;
type MutationOptions = UseMutationOptions<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

For closely coupled types you could use `infer` to derive complex types from the complex elements which made the original.

[This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=75#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYBLA9gOygHgIIBoAhfAYQD4oBeKAbQOJIF0BuAKFdEigCUIA3CPADOEACZxBydBjxFSFajRJzcLdp2i8BwiNgAqUCAA9gEDKKGwEUzNkQYQ+e4+dkFUA8dPnLEpKlsUDAAzQSgCKCDQ+ChiSJCw8igAfh5+QRFxawCZenkoAC4oDHT4Ng5waAA5AFcAWwAjQT8bDCrEOuhqACJEUVFuqAAfKG6hGobgJABjYEGR7rqagBtUMGWQedHRFD4UUQhu9UqoWsbm7OkqK0kc7DOm+Bac9s78YvrH-AxPwTJyjRpbSZB4XW5XahaDK6UFPS6Yf7saaYITAKDwUog35w8GYApQnSiWHPCG0AAs+AAzPhFis1htuiwoEA) contains an example where one type unpacks the complex bits of another type using infer. `Reverse` simplifies creating the `ReversedNumberOperation` by getting the type details from `NumberOperation` without specifying anything about `number` or `NumberOperationNames`.

```
type Operation <A,B,C> = [A,B,C];

type ReversedOperation<A,B,C> = [C,B,A];

type Reverse<T extends Operation<any,any,any>> = T extends Operation<infer A, infer B, infer C> ? ReversedOperation<A,B,C> : never;

type NumberOperationName = "add" | "subtract" | "multiply" | "divide"

type NumberOperation = Operation<NumberOperationName, number,number>;

type ReversedNumberOperation = Reverse<NumberOperation>;

const reversedNumberOperation:ReversedNumberOperation = [4,3,"multiply"];
```

I've been tempted to go down this route before, but usually decided it wasn't worth it compared to everything being explicit.

Comment: Had to fix my answer a few times. The original example was shonky and then when I copy-pasted the new playground link with the improved version there were editor formatting problems which needed a few goes around before StackOverflow would render the code block properly.